# Transformation from Object frame to World frame

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I try to view the motions of a camera sensor in an OpenGL viewer, but I am having a hard time transforming the object frame into the world frame.

Coordinate system of the camera sensor:
[image]

And the camera sensor returns the rotations in the order `z x y` in the rotation matrix.
So I thought that a multiplication with the following matrix would work:

```
 0  0  1
-1  0  0
 0 -1  0
```

But all rotations are inverted, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.
The rotation matrix coming from the camera sensor has a row major layout, and my matrix class has a column major layout which is different from glm (used in my OpenGL viewer). The rotation matrix multiplications were messed up!